# Spring Boot 3 Native yaml composition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-native

The objective is to reuse some yaml with default configurations within the configuration yaml per environment.

In non-native mode, I can perform these compositions in some ways, but not yet with the native build.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to make this type of feature work in native mode?

[GitHub](https://github.com/biroska/compose/tree/master/src/main)

Spring Boot Main class

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class CompositionApplication {

    @Value("${application.version}")
    private String version;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CompositionApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return MessageFormat.format("Hello World! {0}", version);
    }
}
```

Application.yaml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: default, dev
    import: "classpath:application-dev.yml"
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
    import: "classpath:application-local.yml"
```

So far everything works as expected, but I haven't found a way to reference the tmdb.yml file within application.yaml

If I add the composition in Yaml, the application does not launch in native mode

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: default, dev
    import: "classpath:application-dev.yml, classpath:tmdb.yml"
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
    import: "classpath:application-local.yml, classpath:tmdb.yml"
```

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class CompositionApplication {

    @Value("${application.version}")
    private String version;

    @Value("${tmdb.api.domain}")
    private String domain;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CompositionApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return MessageFormat.format("Hello World! {0} - Domain {1}", version, domain);
    }
}
```

After including the yaml composition, the application exe opens and closes. Closing the application and not allowing the stacktrace to be viewed.

I am using
GraalVM 20
Spring Boot 3.1.3